# Условный оператор?

Tags: c#

Вот код

```
bool t1;
if(t.Length>=2)
    if (t[1] == "да")
       t1 = true;
       else
           t1 = false;
```

Как это будет выглядеть в в условном операторе ?

пытался решить его так

```
bool t1 = (t.Length >= 2) ? (t1[1]=="да")? true : false;
```

но выдает синтаксическую ошибку. Как правильно написать?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64143/discussion-on-question-by-polsok--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код может быть переписан следующим образом.

```
bool t1 = t.Length>=2 && t[1] == "да";
```

Пояснение. В C# при проверке логического И - `&&` происходит проверка на `true` всех операндов, слева на право. Первый попавшийся операнд со значением `false` обрывает дальнейшие вычисления.
В качестве примера:

```
public static bool ThrowExceptionMethod()
{
    throw new Exception("ThrowExceptionMethod()");
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (false && ThrowExceptionMethod())
        Console.WriteLine("true");
    else 
        Console.WriteLine("false");
}
```

Результат:

```
false
```